# Chrome extension wait for settings to be loaded in an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events

I am developing a Chrome extension with settings (basically two flags) persisted in the Chrome local storage. I can save and retrieve the saved settings fine on the options page like this:

Save:

```
function save_options() {
  var checkbox1checked = $("#checkbox1").prop("checked");
  var checkbox2checked = $("#checkbox2").prop("checked");
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    checkbox1: checkbox1checked,
    checkbox2: checkbox2checked 
  }, function() {
    $("#status").text("Settings saved.");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       $("#status").text("");
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

Retrieve:

```
function restore_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    checkbox1: true,
    checkbox2: false
  }, function(items) {
    $("#checkbox1").prop("checked", items.checkbox1);
    $("#checkbox2").prop("checked", items.checkbox2);
  });
}
```

And then in my content script I wrote a function to retrieve the settings just like this:

```
var checkbox1Checked = true;
var checkbox2Checked = false;
    function getSettings() {
      chrome.storage.sync.get({
        checkbox1: true,
        checkbox2: false
      }, function(items) {
        checkbox1Checked = items.checkbox1;
        checkbox2Checked = items.checkbox2;
      });
    }
```

And I am adding an event handler for the 'paste' event like this:

```
window.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste, true);
```

And in the `handlePaste` function, I am calling the `getSettings()` function. But the problem is, the further logic of the event makes the decision whether the event should be cancelled based on the extension settings.

My logic is after the `getSettings()` call, but apparently it runs before the variables are initialized with the updated values since I can only see the correct functionality from the second occurrence of the paste event.

So I am looking for a way to somehow wait for the settings to be loaded and then proceed with the event handler execution. Things I have already tried:

1. I have tried to write my logic in the callback for the settings retrieval. But this does not work since the handler function returns after registering the callback, and additional handlers continue to run while the async operation is in progress, making the event cancellation later impossible.
2. I have tried to wait for the settings to be loaded with `window.setTimeout` and other similar solutions, to no avail.
3. It occurred to me that when I save the settings, I could send some kind of message from the options page to all the pages on which the content scripts run letting them now about the changed settings. I have not yet tried to implement this, and I am not sure if this is even possible.
4. I have tried to somehow clone the event, then cancel it and when the settings are loaded, re-fire the cloned event if necessary. But I have had difficulties with cloning a paste event in the first place.

How should I solve this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated, please bear in mind that this is my first Chrome Extension (I am developing it for personal use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content script should retrieve the settings as soon as it starts and then exit. Execution should continue in the callback function of the `chrome.storage.sync.get()` call, which should use `chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener()` to add an event handler for the `chrome.storage.onChanged` event so that the retrieved settings can be kept up-to-date. The retrieved settings should be stored in a variable which can be accessed by the paste event handler so that it always has access to the current values of the settings. Eg

```
var checkbox1Checked, checkbox2Checked;
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    checkbox1: true,
    checkbox2: false
}, function(items) {
    checkbox1Checked = items.checkbox1;
    checkbox2Checked = items.checkbox2;
    chrome.storage.sync.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, area) {
        if (area !== "sync") return;
        if (changes.checkbox1) {
            checkbox1Checked = changes.checkbox1.newValue;
        }
        if (changes.checkbox2) {
            checkbox2Checked = changes.checkbox2.newValue;
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste, true);
});
```

Now the paste event handler can access the settings immediately in the variables `checkbox1Checked` and `checkbox2Checked` without having to call `chrome.storage.sync.get()`. The handler is added in the `chrome.storage.sync.get()` callback function so that it cannot be invoked before the settings variables have been initialized.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. Works perfectly. One small correction which I had to make in order to make it work:
"chrome.storage.sync.onChanged.addListener" --> "chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener".